# 403 response code for any POST request to Interactive Brokers Client Portal Web API

Tags: http-post, http-status-code-403, interactive-brokers

I try use Interactive Brokers Client Portal Web API:

- I succesfully start gateway and login.
- I succesfully make GET requests to various end-points.
- When I make POST request to any end-points, I receive 403 response code.

For example, I try update currently selected account:

```js
// it is need for change User-Agent as recommended*
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function (details) {
    for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
        if (details.requestHeaders[i].name === 'User-Agent') {
            details.requestHeaders[i].value = 'Console';
            break;
        }
    }
    return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
}, {urls: ['<all_urls>']}, ['blocking', 'requestHeaders']);

// it is code of make of POST request
var data = {};
data['acctId'] = 'U1234567';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://localhost:5000/v1/portal/iserver/account', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        sendResponse({Status: xhr.status + '_' + xhr.responseText}); // I have "403_" response
    }
};
```

*: [Making POST request from console app results in Error 403 - Access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64597071/making-post-request-from-console-app-results-in-error-403-access-denied)

Headers of my request:

```
Cookie: SBID=xskr4cf7kflki7wrzzy; XYZAB_AM.LOGIN=29c2d567b3a3f23d8d02bdd5ef78d0c8c2694438; XYZAB=29c2d567b3a3f22d8d12bdd5ef78d0c8c2694438; api=673d21e86cf499f04b985446a90a844b; ibkr.nj=286565962.20480.0000
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,uk;q=0.6
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Origin: chrome-extension://jnblchdcckkmedocgchlfmfhbaihjdnl
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: Console
Content-Length: 21
Connection: close
Host: localhost:5000
```

Body of my request:

```
{"acctId":"U1234567"}
```

Answer (score 3):

As described above, we can resolve this by adding 'User-Agent': 'Console' to the header. You can use Python requests to send the header alongwith as below.

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Console', 'content-type': 'application/json'}

response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, verify='path to .pem file or False if SSL is not needed')
```

where url is the string containing the post URL and data is the json data you need to submit to POST request.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by populating the User-Agent and sending an empty string as the POST payload to ensure the Content-Length header was being set, ex. calls made to the /tickle endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.
The fact is that a “Client Portal WebAPI gateway” is not just a gateway, it is a server that allows you to host your HTML-pages with your code on it.
After launching the gateway as described here https://interactivebrokers.github.io/cpwebapi/index.html#login
and authorization on the https://localhost:5000/ page,
you can go to the https://localhost:5000/demo/#/ and see a small demo application with very complex code, which is beyond my primitive knowledge. Therefore, I replaced the index.html file in the root\webapps\demo folder with my own and wrote my own javascript code for the POST-request

```
var data={};
data["symbol"]="RSG";
data["name"]=false;
data["secType"]="STK";
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "https://localhost:5000/v1/portal/iserver/secdef/search", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xhr.readyState==4)
        {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
```

and it worked, since now the index.html page of my application and the end-point are on the same domain localhost:5000, so mod_security rejection does not occur and everything works!

Comment: Your workaround only applies by using the same API calls within the same component, which I think is not optimal as you will not be able to build an external application using REST API from the Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

did you performe insecure https POST requests ?

On my side insecure https GET requests are working fine, but I think it generates "403" for POST requests. On my way to try with a self-signed cert

Comment: Yes I make insecure https POST requests. I also thought that the reason was an expired certificate, but what was the real reason I described above. Now I see a warning that the connection is not secure, but everything works.

Answer (score 0):

The question was marked as resolved, but I managed to resolve the similar issue by simply setting the User-Agent in the header to anything. My current app is NodeJS using the request module. Set the User-Agent to quite literally anything and make sure you handle the insecure SSL certificate.