# Place an order in Interactive Brokers using API request

Tags: python, api, gateway, interactive-brokers

First, to begin with, I was successfully able to place an order using TWS API. However, for that, as I understood, I need to run the TWS desktop version in the background. But I need to run this on my remote server. So I used a [3rd party API called IBeam](https://github.com/Voyz/ibeam) and created a gateway using it, in the remote server. Now it is working well and serving the GET requests that I request from the Interactive Brokers.

Now, I want to place an order in Interactive Broker, using an API request and found [this doc](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/api/doc.html#tag/Order/paths/%7E1iserver%7E1account%7E1%7BaccountId%7D%7E1orders/post) by IB. However, for me it is not clear what they meant by each argument, so as of now I am stuck. I.e, from docs, I need to send a POST request to https://localhost:5000/v1/api/iserver/account/{accountId}/orders (with IB gateway running in localhost:5000) with the request body

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "acctId": "string",
      "conid": 0,
      "secType": "secType = 265598:STK",
      "cOID": "string",
      "parentId": "string",
      "orderType": "string",
      "listingExchange": "string",
      "isSingleGroup": true,
      "outsideRTH": true,
      "price": 0,
      "auxPrice": null,
      "side": "string",
      "ticker": "string",
      "tif": "string",
      "referrer": "QuickTrade",
      "quantity": 0,
      "fxQty": 0,
      "useAdaptive": true,
      "isCcyConv": true,
      "allocationMethod": "string",
      "strategy": "string",
      "strategyParameters": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

From what I learn from the TWS API, this was all the information needed to place an order:

```
    contract = Contract()
    contract.symbol = "AAPL"
    contract.secType = "STK"
    contract.exchange = "SMART"
    contract.currency = "USD"
    contract.primaryExchange = "NASDAQ"

    order = Order()
    order.action = "BUY"
    order.totalQuantity = 10
    order.orderType = "MKT"
```

It would be great if you could help me with a sample code to place a similar order using the REST API of Ineteractive Broker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [this article](https://www.tradersinsight.news/ibkr-quant-news/how-to-code-an-ib-algo-order-in-the-web-api/) helpful in the process of placing an order.

I.e, this is a sample request that you can use to place an order

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "acctId": "DU4299134",
      "conid": 8314,
      "secType": "8314:STK",
      "cOId": "testAlgoOrder",
      "orderType": "LMT",
      "price": 142,
      "side": "BUY",
      "tif": "DAY",
      "quantity": 1,
      "strategy": "Adaptive",
      "strategyParameters": {"adaptivePriority": "Normal" }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can use these URLs to find more info about the strategies,

```
url = f"https://localhost:5000/v1/api/iserver/contract/{conid}/algos"
url_more_info = f"https://localhost:5000/v1/api/iserver/contract/{conid}/algos?addDescription=1&addParams=1&algos={algos}"
```

Further, when you place an order like above, IBKR will ask you to confirm the  order, which you can do by

```
url = f"https://localhost:5000/v1/api/iserver/reply/{replyid}"

data = '''{
  "confirmed": true
}'''

response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, verify='path to .pem file')
```

Note that you have to use the correct header when you are sending a POST requests to IBKR as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65305153/403-response-code-for-any-post-request-to-interactive-brokers-client-portal-web/69027259#69027259).